# Recursion of $S_n=x_1^n + x_2^n + x_3^n$

Tags: polynomials

Let $S_n=x_1^n + x_2^n + x_3^n, S_1 = \alpha, x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1=\beta,x_1x_2x_2=\gamma$. So, $S_n = \ ?$
I know $s_2 = \alpha^2 - 2\beta,\\ s_3=\alpha^3 - 3\alpha\beta + 3\gamma, \\s_4=\alpha^4 - 4\alpha_1^2\beta+2\beta^2+4\alpha\gamma$

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x_1,x_2,x_3$ are roots of $P(x)=x^3-\alpha x^2+\beta x-\gamma$.

Then, plugging in $x_i$ and multiplying by $x_i^n$ you get

$$x_i^{n+3}-\alpha x_i^{n+2}+\beta x_i^{n+1}-\gamma x_i^{n}=0 \,.$$

Adding the three relations we get the relation Thomas Andrews wrote:

$$S_{n+3}-\alpha S_{n+2}+\beta S_{n+1}-\gamma S_{n}=0 \,.$$

Answer (score 3):

You can write $S_{n+3}=\alpha S_{n+2} -\beta S_{n+1} + \gamma S_n$.

You can also write out explicitly:

$$S_n = \sum_{i+2j+3k=n}_{i,j,k\geq 0} (-1)^j\frac{n}{i+j+k}\binom{i+j+k}{i,j,k}\alpha^i\beta^j\gamma^k$$

One way to see the above recurrence is to consider:

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty S_it^i = \frac{1}{1-x_1t}+\frac{1}{1-x_2t} + \frac{1}{1-x_3t}\\=\frac{3-2\alpha t+\beta t^2}{1-\alpha t+\beta t^2-\gamma t^3}$$

Mutliplying both sides by $1-\alpha t+\beta t^2-\gamma t^3$ gives you the recurrence.